# iPhone: why is the Add Call button disabled for 15 seconds?

Tags: iphone

When I make a phone call, the add call button is disabled for 15 seconds... I.e. it's grayed out. Then it becomes active and works as I expect. But how I can set up conference calls without this delay every time?

Comment: @Gerry is that relevant?  The upvotes give much more reputation than the accepts...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes it is relevant. It's part of how these sites work, and reviewing his questions there are plenty that have acceptable answers. If you expect people to spend their time on answering your questions it's only courtesy to take the time to accept or comment on the answers you got.

Answer (score 1):

You can only make a second call once the first call is connected. That delay is to connect and set up the first call.